# Reading parquet file as is using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, clickhouse, apache-spark-dataset

I want to read parquet file as is using spark and process each file's content one by one.
I was trying to achieve it using following approach

```
    spark.read
      .option("wholetext", "true")
      .option("compression", "none")
      .textFile("/test/part-00001-d3a107e9-ead6-45f0-bccf-fadcecae45bb-c000.zstd.parquet")
```

Also tried many different similar approaches to this, but Spark seems to be modifying the file content somehow, because of absence of some option probably added when reading it.

My final goal is to load those files in Clickhouse using okhttp client in Scala. The file I am trying to load is not corrupted and Clickhouse successfully processes it, when not used in Spark.
However, when I try to use spark with the following approach Clickhouse responds `std::exception. Code: 1001, type: parquet::ParquetException, e.what() = Couldn't deserialize thrift: TProtocolException: Invalid data`
When I try to print out the content of whatever I read from the file I see this

```
Europe/Moscoworg.apache.spark.version3.4.1)org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata�{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"field1","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"field2","type":{"type":"array","elementType":"integer","containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"field3","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"x","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"y","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}org.apache.spark.legacyDateTimeJparquet-mr version 1.12.3 (build f8dced182c4c1fbdec6ccb3185537b5a01e6ed6b)L^PAR1
```

Which doesn't look like it has any data within it, and appears to only have metadata.

My question is how to read the parquet file as is in binary in string format using Spark.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try using  spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles ([BinaryFiles code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f5cf310199132f62b779e0244d15f7680e2ba856/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1176C19-L1176C19) ) ?

```
val files: RDD[(String, PortableDataStream)] = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("/path/to/parquet/files/")
files.foreach { case (path, stream) =>
  // Use the `stream` PortableDataStream to get InputStream and read the binary content
  // Process or write the binary content to Clickhouse
}
```

Another way would be to use Javas [nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) API :

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

val bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/parquet/file"))
```

Comment: First one works well with binaryFiles, thank you.
Second one is not suitable since there is a requirement to do it in distributed manner at least.

Comment: If it works please accept the answer  as it will be then relevant for other people too that have the same question / use case